# Cannot pair/connect to the Bluetooth in my Mazda 3

Tags: mazda, mazda-3, bluetooth

I have a 2010-2012-ish era Mazda 3 that has the Bluetooth option in its menu. When I attempt to pair a phone it fails, despite me going through the steps correctly?

How can I pair my phone? Do I have to buy a new Bluetooth module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching high and low I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F8PW9IHliSc) youtube video that solved my issue.

In a nutshell:

- It seems that trying to pair with the default pin (`0000`) does not work.
- You need to set a different pin by pushing the numbered buttons on your console (mine look different to the video, but they work the same).
- I set a pin of `1111` by pushing the buttons 1 through 4 once each.
- After this the pairing worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Those smart tablets get glitchy sometime ,try resetting the car via removing the battery terminals for a period of time and reconnecting it , to reinitialize the infotainment system (take note of radio code if preset!).